# Ошибка 'git cannot open 'git-receive-pack' при попытке запушить проект

Tags: git

Вчера появилась ошибка `git cannot open git-receive-pack` при попытку протолкнуть изменения в репе. Я пользуюсь мобильным клиентом **SGit** на своем Android устройстве для работы с Git. Пользуюсь долго и успешно. Но вчера совершенно неожиданно вылезла эта ошибка. Google посоветовал прописать в git config следующее - `sslVerify = false`. Сделал. Не помогло.

Причем даже клонирование репы, которое раньше работало через `https://github.com/User/Repo` тоже перестало работать по причине той же ошибки. По совету Google удалось провести клонирование  через `git://github.com/User/Repo`, но запушить проект все равно не удается ни первым ни вторым способом.

Что могло спровоцировать подобную ошибку и как её исправить?

Comment: github не так давно что-то из "устаревших" протоколов запретил. Честно слабо помню, что там было. Потому советы такие - попробовать другой гит клиент, уточнить версию андроида (старые точно могли от этого отвалиться).

Comment: Да, честно, говоря, уже десяток перепробовал, результат тот же.

Comment: Если поискать на en so, то там в основном на проблемы сетевого слоя ссылаются - рекомендуют отключить `git config http.sslVerify false` проверку сертификата, выключить Fiddler2 для https и т.п.

Comment: Ну, так я же в вопросе написал, что так и сделал. Это тоже не помогает.

Comment: А сайты https://github.com и https://api.github.com с телефона открываются? Ну и да, клонирование через git:// сработало, значит в теории можно попробовать доступ по ssh, но тут лучше в гугле поискать, как его можно настроить.

Comment: Да, через браузер github нормально открывается.